# unable to traverse up the dom using jquery ajax success callback function

Tags: jquery

In the below html i am trying to traverse up the DOM using $(this) but some problem i am unable to find.

```
<div class="albumWrapper">
    <div class="album" id="test1">
        <div class="fadein">
            <img src="images/album/1_b.jpg" />
            <img src="images/album/2_b.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="descWrapper">
            <h1>
                <a href="1">Weddings</a>
            </h1>
            <div class="description">
                <span class="quotes">"</span>description 1<span class="quotes">"</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
    <div class="album" id="test1">
        <div class="fadein">
            <img src="images/album/1_b.jpg" />
            <img src="images/album/2_b.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="descWrapper">
            <h1>
                <a href="2">Weddings</a>
            </h1>
            <div class="description">
                <span class="quotes">"</span>description 2<span class="quotes">"</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

This is jquery I have written. But itseems to have some problem when i am using $(this).
So please someone help me find the mistake. It would be helpful.

```
        $(".descWrapper h1 a ").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajaxify/gallery.php',
                type: "get",
                data: "id=" + $(this).attr('href'),
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $(this).parents(".album").next(".gallery").html(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: can you explain are you trying to do first?

Comment: Are you refering to $(this) in success function? Isn't that in another scope? Try defining a variable "albums" right after preventDefault() and use that variable

Comment: learnt a lesson not to use this in success :) thanks

Comment: @susheel of course you can use this in callback functions of ajax, just set correct context

Comment: yes, just saw your solution it is much clearner and i am clear about the context stuff thanks :) :) @roasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use context option of ajax:

```
$(".descWrapper h1 a ").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        context:this,
        url: 'ajaxify/gallery.php',
        type: "get",
        data: "id=" + $(this).attr('href'),
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            //now 'this' here refers to the clicked link
            $(this).parents(".album").next(".gallery").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Old question that helped me with a different problem, but .parents() instead of .parent() gave me a clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the `success` function isnt the right scope, it will not be the ".descWrapper h1 a " element. So set `this` to a variable before hand and use the variable instead of `this`

```
$(".descWrapper h1 a ").on("click", function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         url: 'ajaxify/gallery.php',
         type: "get",
         data: "id=" + $(this).attr('href'),
         beforeSend: function() {

         },
         success: function(data) {
              element.parents(".album").next(".gallery").html(data);
         },
         error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
             alert();
         }
    });
});
```