# How do i refresh the html form after successfully updated the data without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've a html form which is updating the form data using Jquery/Ajax method. After successfully updated it's showing "Success Message". That's fine but it's remain form contents. I want to reload/refresh the form / form contents after update is done without page refresh. How can I do this ? Can you guys give an Solution or idea about it ? Thank you.

**My jquery code is following**

if you need my html form then I will upload it to here. :)

```
<script>
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'editContactDetails.php',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                return myXhr;
            },
           success: function(data){                    
            $("#success").html(data);
            //alert(response);
        },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
})
</script>
```

Update:

```
<div id="showContactsDetails">
<h2>Individual Record Details</h2>

<div style=" visibility:hidden;" id="visiable">

<span class="mandatory"><sub>* Required</sub></span>
        <!--success update -->  
        <div id="success"></div>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="all_contact_details">
<table width="450" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
  <input type="hidden" name="cdid" id="cdid"/>
  </tr>     
  <tr>
    <td>Company Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" disabled="disabled"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Family name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="family_name" id="family_name"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Given name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="given_name" id="given_name"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Work Phone</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="work_phone" id="work_phone"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mobile Phone</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email address</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Private email address</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email_private" id="email_private"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Upload your document</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_1" id="file_des1" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input name="file1" type="file" id="file" class="file"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_2" id="file_des2" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input type="file" name="file2" id="file_2" class="file"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_3" id="file_des3" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input type="file"  name="file3" id="file_3" class="file"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_4" id="file_des4" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input type="file"  name="file4" id="file_4" class="file"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" name="submit" value="Update Details" class="submit" id="upload"/></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
</form> 
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: call `reset()` on form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this

**pure javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();
```

**jquery:**

```
$("#all_contact_details")[0].reset();
```

**complete code:**

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data){                    
            $("#success").html(data);
            document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();
            //$("#all_contact_details")[0].reset();
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi do you know why it's not working now after using your code?

Comment: `context:this` did you add this in your code and whats the error in console

Comment: Error in Console log : `TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
 

$('#all_contact_details').validate({`

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function
 

$("#all_contact_details").reset();`

Comment: `document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();`

Comment: I've a one more questions to you. Can I ask you ?

Comment: Actually it's updated the form with data and files. so I want to show the form data and uploaded file (with a link for download) again after reload the page. is it possible ?

Comment: @Babu then you have to do it on serverside when page refreshes you can echo the formdata and the file you have posted.

Comment: Ok Thank you. Received great help from you. :)

Answer (score 2):

just reset in success function:

```
$("#success").html(data);
$this.closest('form').get(0).reset();
```

---

You can do this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this); // cache the current context of selector
    var formData = new FormData($this.closest('form')[0]); // update this

    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data){                    
           $("#success").html(data);
           $this.closest('form').get(0).reset();
           // or if above not work then try this
           //$this.closest('form').find(':input:not(#upload)').val('');
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: It's seems not working. I've 2 thml form tag in this page. So is it the problem ?

Comment: @Babu would you post your html structure.

Comment: Sure I'm posting it now.

Comment: You mentioned two forms this is just one, i suppose that is in other div wrapper and that do not have same id.

Comment: make sure your both forms have different ids. would you confirm this?

Comment: Downvote because that doesn't work...check my answer...There is no direct function reset in jquery. you need to rely on pure javascript way. or jquery with index 0 to match first form

Comment: `$this.closest('form').get(0).reset();` would do as well.

Comment: but you didn't do that..post that and i will remove the downvote

Comment: @susheel get +1 from myside.

Comment: @shusheel i like it.`;)`

Comment: using `context:this` would be better option . as it is already there. :)

Comment: yeah can be used but as we are already working in a current context so i think that does not make a difference because op is using `success` callback not `.done()`.

Comment: @Jai
i came accross some issue with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378085/unable-to-traverse-up-the-dom-using-jquery-ajax-success-callback-function